# Android application for analyzing apks

Tags: android, security

This one is for all the side loaders.

I basically want an app like this

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sk.styk.martin.apkanalyzer

It analyzes the installed applications' permissions, activities.

This kind of analysis would be useful before sideloading an all.

But unfortunately this app only analyses installed apks.

I want an apk analyzer that can give me analysis of an apk on memory card.

I want to be able to view permissions and if possible other details.

A privacy permission breakdown is also acceptable.